# How To Install Latest Nodejs on CentOS?

Tags: node.js, centos, centos7

I following a few tutorials and nothing works. Here is what I do :

```
yum install -y gcc-c++ make
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum install nodejs
```

It never upgrades the version and I always get

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 66.23.237.210
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 66.23.237.210
 * cpanel-plugins: 66.23.237.210
 * base: centos.mirror.vexxhost.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.colo-serv.net
 * updates: mirror.dst.ca
Package 2:nodejs-13.14.0-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: Try ```sudo yum reinstall nodejs```

Comment: Try node version manager (NVM)